# How to pass multiple Models to Laravel View

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project, I am trying to display some data from the database. The data is looked up from multiple tables. The structure looks like this:

- Group ( e.g. name = "G1")

  - Book ( e.g. name = "B1")
  - Pencil (e.g. name = "P1")
  - Ink    (e.g. name = "I1")
- Group (e.g. name = "G2")

  - Book ( e.g. name = "B2")
  - Pencil (e.g. name = "P2")
  - Ink    (e.g. name = "I2")

Group, Book, Pencil & Ink are Eloquent/Model classes. I can lookup the data fine (with all the relationship between the tables). Now, I want to send this data to the Laravel view php, so that it can be displayed. At the view php, there will be drop-down element for Group with group name (e.g. "G1" or "G2") displayed, so if the user select "G1", the page should display all the G1 related info (e.g. B1, P1, I1) and for "G1", it's related info. By default (or on page load), first group in the list and its related info should be displayed.

I want to know how should I pack the data (I believe is some array) and use it in view php? And also how to update the view when the selection has changed in the Group dropdown?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller method

```
$groupOne = Group::where()->get(); // Your Group One Query, Whatever It May Be
$groupTwo = Group::where()->get(); // Your Group Two Query, Whatever It May Be

return view('pathTo.someView', compact('groupOne', 'groupOne'));
```

You will be able to loop through these in your blade temeplate. Ex:

```
@foreach( $groupOne as $item ) 

@endforeach

@foreach( $groupTwo as $item ) 

@endforeach
```

If you want to change the view/content of the page  depending on change of a dropdown, you are going to have to use JavaScript for that. Laravel comes with [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) out of the box. I suggest starting there for dynamically changing content.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Got a question `return view('pathTo.someView', compact('groupOne', 'groupOne'));` Pardon my ignorance, this returns two strings back to view ?

Comment: Check the [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function in the php manual. It uses the two variable names as reference and creates an array of their values. What is sent to the view is an array with 2 keys: 'groupOne' and 'groupTwo', each containing the respective collection as their value.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
$groupOne = Group::where()->get();
$groupTwo = Group::where()->get();
```

We can use this command when there is 1 or 2

```
return view('pathTo.someView', compact('groupOne', 'groupOne'));
```

We can use an another method like this.

```
$params = [
            'groupOne' => $groupOne,
            'groupTwo' => $groupTwo,
            'groupThree'=>$groupThree,
            'groupFour'=>$groupFour,
            ];
return view('pathTo.someView')->with($params);
```

Use these in blades as follows..

```
@foreach( $groupThree as $item ) 
@endforeach

@foreach( $groupfour as $item ) 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each model a variable, and pass it to the view method. It's the second argument: I use `compact('customerModel', 'staffModel')`; looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

First, you gather the data you need with an eloquent query:

```
$groups= \App\Group::where('')->get();
```

This method returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) class with a bunch of helper methods. If you want a single instance, use ->first() instead.

Then you can pass your data to a view in a second parameter like this:

```
return view('myview', [
    'groups' => $groups
]);
```

And finally, you can use blade templating directives to render your list in your view file:

```
<select>
@foreach($groups as $group)
   <option>{{$group->book->attribute}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

To update the dropdown selections dynamically, you need to use dynamic JavaScript to show the relevant dropdown. If you have a lot of groups or other models, you should probably only fetch a single group at a time using ajax when the selection is changed. When using ajax to load the lists dynamically, you can use the blade directive to render the initial list but cannot rely on it to update your views since blade is a server side rendering engine and cannot change it's content dynamically after the view has been sent to the clientside.